# AlmaLinux8でドメイン名を指定してssh接続を許可するには

Tags: linux

CentOS7でTCP Wrapperを使用し、hosts.allowに以下のような記述をしてドメイン名を限定したssh接続を許可していました。

```
sshd: .dion.ne.jp
```

AlmaLinux8を使うことになったのですが、同様に設定するための方法を調べたのですがわかりませんでした。IPアドレスが決まる場合はfirewall-cmdの--add-rich-ruleで設定出来ることは把握しているのですが・・・。

どなたか識者の方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いします。

**追記**

pamを使えば良いことがわかりましたが、IPアドレスでの指定では動作してくれますが、ドメイン名を指定しても動いてくれません。
access.confに以下のように記述しましたが接続できませんでした。

```
+ : testuser : .vmobile.jp
```

ドメイン名で指定するためには何か設定が必要でしょうか。

Comment: CentOSタグが付けられていましたが、CentOSは参考情報で知りたいのはAlmaLinuxですよね？ プロバイダ名とありましたがそれは「au one net」であり、実際に指定するのはドメイン名ですよね？

Comment: AlmaLinuxでタグ付けできなかったのでCentOSタグをつけました。

Comment: ドメイン名での指定です。

Comment: @sayuri タグについては英語版、(よりサーバの話題に特化した) Server Fault でも Alma Linux のタグはまだ使われていませんでした。一応は互換 OS なので、よほど固有の話題でない限りひとまず CentOS タグでもよさそうな気もします。

Comment: ドメイン名の正引きができるよう DNS の設定は済んでいる状態ですか？

Comment: @cubick CentOSもAlmaLinuxもRHEL互換OSなので兄弟関係でしかないです。仮につけるならばrhelにすべきかと。

Comment: @cubick セキュリティ周りで接続できないようでした。別のドメインのホストを設定し、そのホストからの接続ができました。

Answer (score 0):

PAM でもできると思いますが、sshd 側で `AllowUsers` で制限する方法もあります。

```
(/etc/ssh/sshd_config)
UseDNS yes
AllowUsers testuser@*.vmobile.jp
```

ただし、以下の条件があります。なりすましを防ぐためと思われます。

**「接続元IPアドレスの逆引きで得られた FQDN (HOST.vmobile.jp) を正引きした結果(IPアドレス)」＝「接続元IPアドレス」**

Comment: pamでもそうですが、どうもまさしく「なりすましを防ぐ」の条件にハマっていたようです。別のドメインを使うと接続できました。